# Problems checking for CSS property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, properties, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to check whether the link in my navbar is underlined/active when the user clicks on it, but none of my JS functions are working.

I've tried everything from

```
 $("#link").click(function() { 
    if($('#link').css('text-decoration') == 'underline') {
       alert("COME ON!");
    }
});
```

to

```
 $("#link").click(function() { 
    if($('.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a').css('text-decoration') == 'underline') {
       alert("COME ON!");
    }
 });
```

I need to know how to do this without modifying my CSS in any way.

Suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class = "active"><a id = "link" href = "#" >Link</a></li>   

                    </ul><!-- END: "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" -->
                </div><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks @Amadan; this is the solution:

```
$(".navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')) {
        alert("COME ON");
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems to work fine in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5xFp/). Maybe your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: it is working:http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/g8NGC/

Comment: Why not just check if `$(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')`? It is more semantic to check if the link is the active link, rather than whether the clicked text has a specific appearance.

Comment: it's working in the fiddle, check your jquery version and use latest jquery, it will bw helpfullll ;)

Comment: Are you guys getting the alert message when you click on "Link"? Because I'm strangely not.

Comment: It's not working for me, either, ReachMM. Perhaps it's a browser issue? But @Amadan's solution is probably a good one.

Comment: Good, someone who's on the same boat as me xD. I'm using Chrome though, so I don't see how anything but the code itself can be the cause of the issue.

Comment: will work in some browsers but chrome will return css3 space separated values with more than just `underline`. Can try using `indexOf()`

Comment: @charlietfl: I am also using Chrome but it works (version 24).

Comment: @Harry working on an app that runs through numerous css properties and we constantly run into multiple space separated values in chrome for this specific css property. This is in V36

Comment: Wow, I never thought the browser would play this much of an issue when it came to this css property specifically.